# Identical SKActions performs slower than the other

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a scene that acts as a menu page for a game and use a UI Button to activate an skaction that moves the camera on the scene and change the menu buttons using a UIView Container.

The code simply moves the camera from the far left to the far right. At the exact same speed. And yet for some reason, the movement to the right is slower than the left?

```
func MoveCameraToRight () {

    let CameraWidth = StartingWidth * SceneCamera.xScale
    let MoveRight = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: (scene?.frame.maxX)!-(CameraWidth/2), y: (camera?.position.y)!), duration: 1)
    camera?.run(MoveRight)

}

func MoveCameraToLeft () {

    let CameraWidth = StartingWidth * SceneCamera.xScale
    let MoveLeft = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: (scene?.frame.minX)!-(CameraWidth/2), y: (camera?.position.y)!), duration: 1)
    camera?.run(MoveLeft)

}
```

As you can see, the durations are exactly the same. Yet for some reason on an iPhone XS Max it appears to be significantly slower than the move left action?

Here's the code that makes those actions run:

```
@IBAction func Openlevels () {

    let Game = (self.view as! SKView).scene as! MainMenuScene
    Game.MoveCameraToRight()

    LevelsContainer.isHidden = false

}

func HideLevels () {

        let Game = (self.view as! SKView).scene as! MainMenuScene
        Game.MoveCameraToLeft()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.LevelsContainer.alpha = 0

        }) { (complete: Bool) in
            self.LevelsContainer.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

And then on the container view to dismiss (and move camera back to the left):

```
@IBAction func Home () {

    let Parent = self.parent as! MainMenu
    Parent.HideLevels()
    Parent.ShowMenu()

}
```

Both SKActions for the camera's position are set to 1, so why would one be slower than the other?

Comment: what does ShowMenu do?

Comment: It tells the parent view to set the alpha of the hidden menu items to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple:

```
let MoveLeft = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: (scene?.frame.minX)!-(CameraWidth/2), y: (camera?.position.y)!), duration: 1)
```

Move left should be min + camWidth/2 not minus. The problem was it was telling the camera to go further than the distance of moving to the right.

```
let MoveRight = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: (scene?.frame.maxX)!-(CameraWidth/2), y: (camera?.position.y)!), duration: 1)
```